# Rust code on Windows: No error messages, but 0 file size on output

Tags: rust

Below is a Rust source file that compiles and **runs without issue** on a Linux platform. When run from the command line, it takes a filename or path/filename string argument, and makes a backup copy of that file if it exists, but with a timestamp in the backup filename along with a ".backup" suffix.

The same code compiles on a Windows platform, but does not run properly after it is compiled. In Windows, the output file is 0 bytes in size. The file gets created, but exists as 0 file size. On Linux, the output file is exactly as one would expect it to be.

Any Rust on Windows programmers see any glaring issues? I don't know my way around Windows OS, and have failed at identifying the issue. I built it for Linux, but I expect a simple fix will get it working on Windows.

If you find the problem, please let me know how you debugged it.

Source repository located here:
[Github Repository](https://github.com/rlovell3/backer)

The only Cargo.toml requirement is:

```
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.26"
```

Below is the complete source:

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::process;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    if args.len() != 2 {
        eprintln!("Usage: backer <target_file>");
        process::exit(1);
    }

    let target_file = PathBuf::from(&args[1]);

    let file_path = if target_file.is_relative() {
        Path::new(".").join(target_file)
    } else {
        target_file
    };

    if !file_path.exists() {
        eprintln!("Error: Target file '{}' does not exist.", file_path.display());
        process::exit(1);
    }

    let current_datetime = chrono::Local::now();
    let formatted_datetime = current_datetime.format("%Y%m%d_%H%M").to_string();
    let backup_filename = format!("{}.{}.backup", file_path.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap(), formatted_datetime);

    let backup_path = file_path.with_file_name(&backup_filename);
    println!("Backup path: {}", backup_path.display());
    
    match fs::copy(&file_path, &backup_path) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Backup successful: {}", backup_path.display()),
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Error during backup: {}", e),
    }
}
```

Comment: From your GitHub repo it seems that the resulting file name contains a colon (`main.20230915:1517.backup`), which can't be part of a file name or path in Windows

Comment: I updated the colon earlier today with an underscore.  The repo should refresh any minute now.  The colon (now an underscore) doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It works fine for me on Windows.

Comment: That is great news.  It suggests something local to me.  Maybe it is a permission issue.  I will look into it, and report it here if I get it.

Comment: I still get a file size of 0 bytes on any file I back up.  I just don't get along well with Windows.

Comment: I fixed it.  Apparently there is apparently a known bug in fs::copy on Windows.  It wasn't known to me, but I really don't operate in a Win environment very often.  I switched to using std::io::copy and that fixed the issue.  I now run it on Windows, and the backed-up version has a file size that equals the file size of the original file.  If anyone finds otherwise, note it here, and I will dig into it once again.  Both the old and the new iterations of the code run well on Linux.